# On landscape screen is rotating not the view on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, autolayout

I m using autolayout,

The screen i designed is working fine in Portrait and Lanscape mode on following devices :

```
1)iPhone 6 Plus : iOS 8.0.2
2)iPhone 5s : iOS 7.0.4
3)iPhone 5 : iOS : 6.1.4
4)iPhone 4 : iOS 7.0.4
```

But not working properly (pls. ref. screenshots) on following devices :

```
1)iPhone 5 : iOS : 8.1
2)iPhone 6 : iOS : 8.1.1
```

[image]

[image]

in these devices the screen is rotating with its status bar but the view remains same like Portrait.
But when i press Home Button to put the app in background and again Double tap to active the App the screen get turn into Landscape along with the status bar and view but almost half of the Portion becomes black

I m using Xcode 6.1.
Pleas help me solving this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you doing this programmatically?

Comment: No, I m just using storyboard and ib without writting single line

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem will you please share your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution ,
just removed following line from launchNavigateScreenWithStoryBoard - AppDelegate.m

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```